# How do I manage multiple FOR loops in Multiview Navigation Event Handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multiview

Please bear with me a bit as I try to explain my problem.

I have multiple GridView controls, each with its own checkbox and textboxes.

User must either check the checkboxes or enter data into all textboxes.

If checkbox is not checked and textboxes within a particular gridview control is empty, when a user clicks the NEXT button of a multiview control, an error is raised.

The following code shows two FOR loops inside button click event of the NEXT navigation button.

The first Gridview1 FOR loop works great. If checkbox is not checked and the textboxes are empty, an alert message is displayed and user cannot navigate to next page.

If however, either the checkbox is checked or textboxes are filled with data, user can then successfully navigate to the next page.

The issue is with the second FOR loop for grvspouse gridview control.

If checkbox is not checked and textboxes are empty, the alert box is displayed with message that user must checkbox or enter data into textboxes. This is fine. However, the problem is that user is still taken to the next page.

Is there a way to handle multiple FOR loops inside BTN_NEXT navigation event handler?

```
Protected Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
    For Each row As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
        Dim namesource As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtsourcename"), TextBox)
        Dim nmesource As String = namesource.Text
        Dim addresssource As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtsourceaddress"), TextBox)
        Dim addrsource As String = addresssource.Text
        Dim incomesource As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtsourceincome"), TextBox)
        Dim incmsource As String = incomesource.Text
        Dim ckb As CheckBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("grid1Details"), CheckBox)
        Dim checkb As Boolean = ckb.Checked
        If checkb = False AndAlso nmesource = "" AndAlso addrsource = "" AndAlso incmsource = "" Then
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Confirm", "jAlert('Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox!');", True)
        Else
            myMultiView.ActiveViewIndex += 1
            lblResult.Visible = True
        End If
    Next

    For Each row As GridViewRow In grvspouse.Rows
        Dim namespouse As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtspousename"), TextBox)
        Dim nmespouse As String = namespouse.Text
        Dim addressspouse As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtspouseaddress"), TextBox)
        Dim addrspouse As String = addressspouse.Text
        Dim incomespouse As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtspouseincome"), TextBox)
        Dim incmspouse As String = incomespouse.Text
        Dim ckb2 As CheckBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("spouseDetails"), CheckBox)
        Dim checkc As Boolean = ckb2.Checked
        If checkc = False AndAlso nmespouse = "" AndAlso addrspouse = "" AndAlso incmspouse = "" Then
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Confirm", "jAlert('Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox!');", True)
        Else
            myMultiView.ActiveViewIndex += 1
            lblResult.Visible = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[Edited]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you coded it that way....The easiest fix would be to create a `STRING VARIABLE` object and by each click,the program would check the `VARIABLE`for a desired value and if the value matches then it'ld move to the next form.A complete example would look like this :

```
 'Create a VARIABLE named HITCOUNT and keep the value empty at first.
  Public class MyProject
  Dim HITCOUNT as string = ""


 If HITCOUNT = "" Then
 For Each row As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
Dim namesource As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtsourcename"), TextBox)
Dim nmesource As String = namesource.Text
Dim addresssource As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtsourceaddress"), TextBox)
Dim addrsource As String = addresssource.Text
Dim incomesource As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtsourceincome"), TextBox)
Dim incmsource As String = incomesource.Text
Dim ckb As CheckBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("grid1Details"), CheckBox)
Dim checkb As Boolean = ckb.Checked
If checkb = False AndAlso nmesource = "" AndAlso addrsource = "" AndAlso incmsource = "" Then
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Confirm", "jAlert('Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox!');", True)
Else
    myMultiView.ActiveViewIndex += 1
    lblResult.Visible = True
End If
Next
HITCOUNT = "1" 'adding an integer value of 1(you can add anything)
End if

If HITCOUNT = "1" then
For Each row As GridViewRow In grvspouse.Rows
Dim namespouse As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtspousename"), TextBox)
Dim nmespouse As String = namespouse.Text
Dim addressspouse As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtspouseaddress"), TextBox)
Dim addrspouse As String = addressspouse.Text
Dim incomespouse As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("txtspouseincome"), TextBox)
Dim incmspouse As String = incomespouse.Text
Dim ckb2 As CheckBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("spouseDetails"), CheckBox)
Dim checkc As Boolean = ckb2.Checked
If checkc = False AndAlso nmespouse = "" AndAlso addrspouse = "" AndAlso incmspouse = "" Then
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Confirm", "jAlert('Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox!');", True)
Else
    myMultiView.ActiveViewIndex += 1
    lblResult.Visible = True
End If
Next
HITCOUNT="2"
End if

  'and move on and on
```

This is just one way and maybe the quickest one.There are many other ways to do so.If you don't wanna use this one, just comment and i'll post another solution

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161576/discussion-on-answer-by-zack-raiyan-how-do-i-manage-multiple-for-loops-in-multiv).